# Pescatarians vs libertarians maths puzzle

Tags: puzzle

The puzzle goes something like this

> In the US every 13th libertarian is a pescatarian and every 11th pescatarian is a libertarian. Are there more libertarians or pescatarians?

The obvious answer seems incorrect to me, yet I don’t know how to go about solving this correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts. A numerical example might help.

Comment: Suppose there are $n$ people who are both.  How many libertarians are there in total in terms of $n$?  How many pescatarians in total in terms of $n$?  Which is bigger?

Comment: "*The obvious answer seems incorrect to me*" What do you think to be the obvious answer and why do you think it to be incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
&&&&&&P&&&&&&\\&&&&&&P&&&&&&\\&&&&&&P&&&&&&\\&&&&&&P&&&&&&\\&&&&&&P&&&&&&\\
L&L&L&L&L&L&\rm both&L&L&L&L&L&L\\
&&&&&&P&&&&&&\\ &&&&&&P&&&&&&\\ &&&&&&P&&&&&&\\ &&&&&&P&&&&&&\\&&&&&&P&&&&&&\\
\end{array}$